# Why custom functions execute automatically in react-native-navigation drawer component during screen render

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new to react-native. I am using react-native-navigation (by wix) for navigating. I have created "Drawerscreen" component for drawer sidebar, under component class I have created a function with name of "navigateToScr". Here "navigateToScr" function calls automatically during initialize component without calling from anywhere, please anyone can explain me why this happening?

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'

export default class Drawerscreen extends Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
  }

  navigateToScr = () =>{
    console.log('in');
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView>
              <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateToScr()} style={styles.menulinkcon}>
                      <Text style={styles.menulink}>Test 1</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateToScr()} style={styles.menulinkcon}>
                      <Text style={styles.menulink}>Test 2</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
              </SafeAreaView>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ ... });
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    screen: {
        screen: "screen.MainScreen",
        title: 'Main Screen',
    },
    drawer: {
        left: {
            screen: 'screen.Drawerscreen',
            fixedWidth: 500
        }
    }
});
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting open & close parenthesis after this.navigateToScr, you're actually calling it and setting onPress to its returned value. If you only want to run the function when it is pressed, instead use

```
onPress={this.navigateToScr}
```

or

```
onPress={() => this.navigateToScr()}
```

The latter is often used when you need to pass a value into the method.

Comment: Is there any reference app available to to learn how to manage screens, components, navigations  etc.

Comment: I imagine there are many - I would search YouTube for React Class components (for example, this series would be one of many: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhkGQAoc7bc). Just keep in mind that referencing a method name will store it for the onClick event. Calling the method (with parenthesis) will store the returned value instead of saving that method for later. It's just another variable.